# Compare different rows within a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 5 columns and many rows. It shows clients, products, dates and some values. I need to compare the values for the same products and the same date. After grouping I get some like this:

```
client  product   date          value1  value2
name1   p1        01/01/2001    10      15
name2   p1        01/01/2001    14      19
name3   p1        01/01/2001    18      22
name2   p2        01/01/2001    10      15
name4   p2        01/01/2001    14      19
name5   p2        01/01/2001    18      22
name1   p1        02/01/2001    10      18
name2   p1        02/01/2001    14      19
name3   p1        02/01/2001    18      22
name1   p2        02/01/2001    10      15
name4   p2        02/01/2001    14      19
name5   p2        02/01/2001    18      22
```

What I need to do now is to get the minimum of the value2 column and the maximum of the value1 column in each group and check if min(value2) < max(value1). If this is true I want to add a comment in a new column to flag that. In this case my desired output is:

```
client  product   date          value1  value2  comments
name1   p1        01/01/2001    10      15
name2   p1        01/01/2001    14      19
name3   p1        01/01/2001    18      22      name1 to name3
name2   p2        01/01/2001    10      15
name4   p2        01/01/2001    14      19
name5   p2        01/01/2001    18      22      name2 to name5
name1   p1        02/01/2001    10      18
name2   p1        02/01/2001    14      19
name3   p1        02/01/2001    18      22
name1   p2        02/01/2001    10      15
name4   p2        02/01/2001    14      19
name5   p2        02/01/2001    18      22      name1 to name5
```

I'm new to pandas and I am completely lost on how to approach this. I managed to do this code that works but it doesn't really do what I want. It fills a whole new column with the minimum value (which is probably not needed). Also, it compares with all the other column instead of the maximum.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
dfg = df.groupby(["product", "date"])
df = df.assign(min2=dfg["value2"].transform(min))
df["comment"] = np.where(df["value1"] > df["min2"], 1, 0)
```

Last, thing I tried to use loc to get the client names but it failed. Any guidance is welcome. Thanks

EDIT: I didn't explain this correctly. The comments needs to take the client name from the row with the min(value2) and the row with the max(value2) and write the comment in one of those two lines. Also, I've added more data in the examples so it's clearer. Thank you for all the answers so far.

Comment: Can you add a bit more sample data? It's hard to write and test code against what you have given here.

Comment: Why the flag message is `name1 to name2`?

Comment: Client name is not an index, so you could not get datafarame series using loc. You may be change to index then you cna loc.

Comment: I've added more data and clarified the comment column. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used `loc` to slice the dataframe accordingly.

```
df['comments'] = np.nan
for p in set(df['product']):
    max_ = df.loc[df['product'] == p,'value1'].max()
    min_ = df.loc[df['product'] == p,'value2'].min()
    if  max_ > min_:
        value_1 = df.loc[(df['product']== p) & (df['value1'] == max_),'client'] #getting the client(s) of the maximum value1
        value_2 = df.loc[(df['product']== p) & (df['value2'] == min_),'client'] #getting the client(s) of the maximum value2
        #commenting according to each name
        for v2 in value_2:
            for v1 in value_1:
                locking = (df['product'] == p) & (df['client'] == v1)
                df.loc[locking,'comments'] = v2 + ' to ' + v1
df

    client  product date        value1  value2  comments
0   name1   p1      01/01/2001  10      15      NaN
1   name2   p1      01/01/2001  14      19      NaN
2   name3   p1      01/01/2001  18      22      name1 to name3
3   name2   p2      01/01/2001  10      15      NaN
4   name4   p2      01/01/2001  14      19      NaN
5   name5   p2      01/01/2001  18      22      name1 to name5
6   name1   p1      02/01/2001  10      18      NaN
7   name2   p1      02/01/2001  14      19      NaN
8   name3   p1      02/01/2001  18      22      name1 to name3
9   name1   p2      02/01/2001  10      15      NaN
10  name4   p2      02/01/2001  14      19      NaN
11  name5   p2      02/01/2001  18      22      name1 to name5
```

This code has found 4 lines instead of three to insert the comment. I believe this is the correct way, as in the index line 8 it finds another incorrect value in name1 vs name3.

Comment: Hi jlb_gouveia. Thank you for your reply. It's really useful. I've edited my question because I need to access the names in the max and min row. It wasn't clear before. My bad

Comment: Hello Javier. If I may ask, what is it that you are trying to achieve? It just seems odd trying to find the maximum of `value_1` and comparing to the minimum `value2`. For example, the 2nd highest value of `value1` could be higher than the minimum value of `value2`, and it would be ignored in the comments. Do all values of 1 need to be smaller than all the values of 2?
Also, I don't see how the comments actually solve any problem. I would just need some context on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Most of the cases value1 would be lower than value2. I just want to check if that is not the case. I don't need the second value because I already flag that there is a potential error in that group. The comment doesn't solve anything it just makes thing easier for whoever review the data later.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll upload a solution I have developed

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use a custom function like this:

```
def f(x):
    x['comments'] = np.nan
    max_v1_idx = x['value1'].idxmax()
    min_v2_idx = x['value2'].idxmin()
    max_v1 = x.loc[max_v1_idx, 'value1']
    min_v2 = x.loc[min_v2_idx, 'value2']
    
    if min_v2 < max_v1:
        x.iloc[-1, x.columns.get_loc('comments')] = x.loc[min_v2_idx, 'client'] + ' to ' +  x.loc[max_v1_idx, 'client'] 
    
    return x
        
df.groupby(['product','date'])\
  .apply(f)
```

Output:

```
   client product        date  value1  value2        comments
0   name1      p1  01/01/2001      10      15             NaN
1   name2      p1  01/01/2001      14      19             NaN
2   name3      p1  01/01/2001      18      22  name1 to name3
3   name2      p2  01/01/2001      10      15             NaN
4   name4      p2  01/01/2001      14      19             NaN
5   name5      p2  01/01/2001      18      22  name2 to name5
6   name1      p1  02/01/2001      10      18             NaN
7   name2      p1  02/01/2001      14      19             NaN
8   name3      p1  02/01/2001      18      22             NaN
9   name1      p2  02/01/2001      10      15             NaN
10  name4      p2  02/01/2001      14      19             NaN
11  name5      p2  02/01/2001      18      22  name1 to name5
```

Details:

Use `groupby` to fetch groups of records from the dataframe.  With `idxmin` and `idxmax` you can return the index of the maximum values for value1 and value2.  `loc` we can fetch the value at that index for value1 and value2.  Compare those values, and assign the last row of the group using `iloc` with -1 and finding the position of comments column using `get_loc`.